# Angular 5 - Bind Observable data in Template when returning an HttpResponse from an API Call

Tags: angular, typescript, observable, httpresponse

I am struggling to understand how to bind data inside a component template, when calling a service that returns a `Observable<HttpResponse<T>>`. Please have a look at my following code and see what I have tried, and what works and what does not.

*Note:* `LeadQueue` is a model, which is just simply an interface with properties on it, so I've omitted it here.

#### metadata.service.ts

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient, HttpParams, HttpResponse } from '@angular/common/http'
import { environment } from 'environments/environment';
import { LeadQueue } from 'app/components/dashboard/models/lead-queue.model';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/observable';

@Injectable()
export class MetadataService {

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }

  fetchLeadQueue(): Observable<HttpResponse<LeadQueue[]>> {
    const PATH = `${environment.metadata_Server}/leads/getqueue`;
    return this.http.get<LeadQueue[]>(PATH, { observe: 'response' });
  }

  // ==========> THIS METHOD WORKS AND BINDS CORREVTLY INSIDE THE TEMPLATE
  fetchLeadQueue2(): Observable<LeadQueue[]> {
    const PATH = `${environment.metadata_Server}/leads/getqueue`;
    return this.http.get<LeadQueue[]>(PATH);
  }

}
```

#### lead-queue.component.ts

```
import { Component, OnInit, Input } from '@angular/core';
import { LeadQueue } from '../models/lead-queue.model';
import { MetadataService } from 'app/core/services/metadata.service';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-lead-queue',
  templateUrl: './lead-queue.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./lead-queue.component.scss']
})
export class LeadQueueComponent implements OnInit {
  leadQueue$: Observable<LeadQueue[]>;
  errorMsg: string;

  constructor(private metadataService: MetadataService) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    // ==========> THE FOLLOWING WORKS, BUT I CANNOT GET THE HTTPRESPONSE OBJECT FROM IT, AND HANDLE IT ACCORDINGLY
    this.leadQueue$ = this.metadataService.fetchLeadQueue2();


    // ==========> THE FOLLOWING HANDLES THE REPONSE CORRECTLY, AND I CAN SEE THE STATUS CODE BEING RETURNED, BUT THE DATA DOES NOT BIND IN THE TEMPLATE

    // this.metadataService.fetchLeadQueue()
    //   .subscribe(
    //     (response) => {
    //         console.dir(response);
    //         // ==========> I AM ABLE TO SEE THE OUTPUT OF THE RESPONSE OBJECT CORRECTLY IN CHROME INSPECTOR CONSOLE, INCLUDING THE STATUS CODE AND THE DATA IS INDEED IN THE RESPONSE.BODY PROPERTY, BUT DOES NOT WORK IN TEMPLATE BINDING.
    //         this.leadQueue$ = response.body;
    //     },
    //     (error) => {
    //       this.errorMsg = 'A fatal error has occurred. Please notify Support.';
    //       console.error(error);
    //     },
    //     () => {
    //       console.log('>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>','[Lead Queue] service call complete.');
    //     }
    //   );
  }  
}
```

#### lead-queue.component.html

```
<table *ngIf="(leadQueue$ | async)?.length > 0; else noData" class="table">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Full Name</th>
      <th>Status</th>
      <th>Vetted</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody *ngFor="let item of leadQueue$ | async">
    <tr>
      <td>{{item.Fullname}}</td>
      <td>{{item.Status}}</td>
      <td>{{item.Vetted}}</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
<ng-template #noData>
  <p class="card-text">No leads available.</p>
</ng-template>
```

As you can see from the above, I've commented which methods/code-blocks work, and which do not. The API call take a fair amount of time to complete, so ideally, I would like to make the call via the service and return the HttpResponse along with the data. In my component, I would like to ensure that the response status code equals `200` and bind the data asynchronously as shown above. However, I've only succeeded in getting **either** the data only to bind (via the `fetchLeadQueue2()` service method), or the Response Object (via the `fetchLeadQueue()` service method) which includes the data correctly in the response.body property, but does not bind in the template.

I would greatly appreciate any advice from the SO community! Many many thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Could you handle the response inside metadata service?

I'm not sure what rxjs version you use, here I use the latest one.

e.g

`metadata.service.ts`

```
  fetchLeadQueue(): Observable<HttpResponse<LeadQueue[]>> {
    const PATH = `${environment.metadata_Server}/leads/getqueue`;
    return this.http.get<LeadQueue[]>(PATH, { observe: 'response' })
      .pipe(
        map(response => response.body), // handle the response here
        catchError(error => console.log(error))      
      );
  }
```

`lead-queue.component.ts`

```
this.leadQueue$ = this.metadataService.fetchLeadQueue();
```

Hope it helps

Comment: Hi deerawan. Thank you for your response. Unfortunately, this did not work. My code is using `rxjs:5.5.5`. I had to handle the `catchError` differently --> `catchError ((error: any) => {return Observable.throw(error.statusText)})`, and that resulted in a **_WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_3_rxjs_observable__.Observable.throw is not a function**. Any ideas?

Comment: @maGz seems you must use this import statement `import { Observable } from 'rxjs';` to import Observable in metadata.service.ts